# how can I make two google maps listeners? setOnCameraChangeListener

Tags: android, google-maps, cluster-computing, android-maps-utils

How can I create two listeners? One is used for the clustering and the other will load new cluster items to the map if no cluster items exists on the map.

```
       //needed for clustering
       map.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);

       // need for loading clusteritems
       map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {

       // ifMarkesNotInsideMapReload...
```

I think it's not possible but someone maybe solved this...

One idea is to set a starting position and poll for changes manually.. not cool :-)

I'm using googles cluster library: [google cluster](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have looked into `ClusterManager` implementation of AMUtils library and it looks like it calls `onCameraChange` on your implementation of `ClusterRenderer` if it also implements `OnCameraChangeListener`. Simply make it implement that interface.

Relevant parts of the code:

```
@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
    if (mRenderer instanceof GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener) {
        ((GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener) mRenderer).onCameraChange(cameraPosition);
    }
```

If you are using `DefaultClusterRendeder`, create a class like:

```
public class MyClusterRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer implements OnCameraChangeListener {
```

Comment: Worked fine! Although I have not understood if I need/should create that mRenderer variable..? Because now the clusters wont show up(the first time) unless i zoom in/out a little bit. Can I call on some refresh/re-render function on the map?

Comment: The reason why my cluster dident display was because the mycluster.cluster() re-clustering method was not called on the main thread.. so heads up :-)

Answer (score 15):

Use the [Composite Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) to create a class that both *is* a `CameraChangeListener` and *contains* `CameraChangeListener`s, such that it can be set as the sole listener on the map while delegating to multiple children that do the real work.

In this case, you would create a `CompositeCameraChangeListener` class which implements the `CameraChangeListener` interface and maintains a list of child listeners it delegates to.

Some pseudocode:

```
public class CompositeCameraChangeListener implements CameraChangeListener {
    private final List<CameraChangeListener> mListeners = new ArrayList<CameraChangeListener>();

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
        for (CameraChangeListener listener in mListeners) {
            listener.onCameraChange(position);
        }
    }

    // Other methods to add, remove listeners
}
```

Then in your main class:

```
CompositeCameraChangeListener composite = new CompositeCameraChangeListener();
composite.add(mClusterManager);
composite.add(new CameraChangeListner() { ... });
map.setOnCameraChangeListener(composite);
```

Now when the `CompositeCameraChangeListener`'s method is invoked, it forwards the call to the other listeners and as far as your app is concerned, you now have two (or more) listeners registered on an object that is designed to only accepted one.

Comment: Looks good to have a separate class for handling camera event. Can be handy.

Comment: This is the best solution. Also one that I implemented is to add the listener to this and redirect the event to all the listeners, is kind of similar to this one without the middle class.

Comment: I was using your solution but today the setOnCameraChangedListener is deprecated by setOnCameraIdleListener which doesn't accept MultiListener as an argument. Do you know a way around?

Comment: @KasparTr The MultiListener is just an example of a design pattern (Composite) to wrap an existing class into one that can act as a group. Just apply the same pattern to `OnCameraIdleListener`

Answer (score 7):

For those struggling on the above pseudo code by TreKing, you can use the code snippet below

```
public class MultiListener implements GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener {
    private List<GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener> mListeners = new ArrayList<GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener>();

    public void registerListener (GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener listener) {
       mListeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition)
    {
        for (GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener ccl: mListeners)
        {
            ccl.onCameraChange(cameraPosition);
        }
    }

}
```

and to add to MultiListener

```
MultiListener ml = new MultiListener();
ml.registerListener(mClusterManager);
ml.registerListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
               @Override
               public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {

                 // code here
               }
           }
    );
map.setOnCameraChangeListener(ml);
```

Answer (score 1):

include cluster manager onCameraChange in your custom camera change listener

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        mClusterManager.onCameraChange(cameraPosition);
        .....
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [**setOnCameraChangeListener** is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setOnCameraChangeListener(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener)), it's better to use **setOnCameraIdleListener**

```
map.setOnCameraIdleListener {
    //...
    clusterManager.onCameraIdle()
}
```